# JS map nested props and string to number

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, map-function

Need help please to change/map this data objects structure from This:

```
var a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({"Meta Data": {"1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes", "2. Symbol": "AAA", "3. Last Refreshed": "2019-10-25", "4. Output Size": "Full size", "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"}, "Time Series (Daily)": {"2019-10-25": {"1. open": "10.7500", "2. high": "11.8100", "3. low": "10.6600", "4. close": "11.7900", "5. volume": "6453477"}, "2019-10-24": {"1. open": "10.7200", "2. high": "10.8050", "3. low": "10.5200", "4. close": "10.6000", "5. volume": "2223747"}}}))
```

Into looking This:

```
var b = [{ time: '2019-10-25', open: 10.7500, high: 11.8100, low: 10.6600, close: 11.7900 },{ time: '2019-10-24', open: 10.7200, high: 10.8050, low: 10.5200, close: 10.6000 }]
```

I am not sure what I need a map or loop that goes into the nested structure to make the new object; where the time keys become values with new key called time ; and also where the open/high/low/close values are no longer string; and the object within the array is flattened as in the desired view.

I have hundreds of thousands of entries so please let me know the fastest/best/easiest way to accomplish this. Thank you.

Comment: What is the point of the `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({ ... }))` step?

Comment: @Pointy, maybe a deep clone of the object? That's one way to do it.

Comment: @AdamAzad what's the point of cloning an object literal that is never assigned to anything else?

Comment: Maybe OP put it that way for the post. Otherwise, your point is valid.

Comment: JSON parse stringify step , to make the JS object, am I using this wrong?

Comment: The point of cloning it into that form is, that it needs to be in that second format like in var b to pass to a charting library.

Comment: The only reason can be that you need a deep clone. But that you would only need if you don't want the original data to get mutated. Is there anything that would mutate the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries` to switch between array/object structures. The inner keys needs to get the number prefix dropped, so for that you can use `split`, `slice` or a more versatile regular expression.

```js
var a = {"Meta Data": {"1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes","2. Symbol": "AAA","3. Last Refreshed": "2019-10-25","4. Output Size": "Full size","5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"},"Time Series (Daily)": {"2019-10-25": {"1. open": "10.7500","2. high": "11.8100","3. low": "10.6600","4. close": "11.7900","5. volume": "6453477"},"2019-10-24": {"1. open": "10.7200","2. high": "10.8050","3. low": "10.5200","4. close": "10.6000","5. volume": "2223747"}}};

let result = Object.entries(a["Time Series (Daily)"]).map(([time, obj]) =>
    ({ time, ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) =>
        [key.replace(/^[\d\. ]+/, ""), isNaN(value) ? value : +value]
    ))})
);
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @tincot For time it needs to be in the flatter format { time: '2019-10-25' , open: ....... } and not in the form of {time:{}, open......} ; how can I tweak it to do this. And BIG THANKS for helping I will study your code to learn how to use those features!

Comment: I don't understand your comment as it is already in that flatter format. Did you run the snippet here and check the output?

Comment: Yes ran it, element zero of the array in the console is as follows->  0: {time : {...}, open: 10.75, high: 11.81, low 10.66, close 11.79,...}

Comment: Instead of -> 0: {time : '2019-10-24', open: 10.75, high: 11.81, low 10.66, close 11.79,...}

Comment: Please let me know if there is a way to de-nest the time as above. Its value is currently-> time: {day: 24, month:10, year: 2019}  want this to be time : '2019-10-24'  Thanks again!

Comment: See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6odP.png) of running this snippet. Please prove your point.

Comment: Not sure why it is nesting the time, but I enclosed the images of the code I ran and the output in console. please see the images: https://ibb.co/ZGybQb6
https://ibb.co/tH8xdhh

Comment: Look here as well to see the nested structure: https://ibb.co/b3ygtk8 I am confused as to why it is doing this and how to fix it.

Comment: I also note in your screenshot that the values only have 2 decimals. So there is a lot more going on. There surely is some code acting on that data before it is being output. Please create a fiddle that reproduces that behaviour, so I can run it.

Comment: Ran in JS fiddle, seems the key time's value has double quotes instead of single quotes. Not sure how to change this; I suspect you are correct that the environment may be picking that up. I suspect this may fix it, but how can I make the time key's value be wrapped in single quotes?

Comment: To see what I mean about the single    '    vs the double    "    I posted an image here: https://ibb.co/QMjW994 Not sure how to change that to single ?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with single or double quotes. That is just how the console represents a string. Whether single or double, either way it is a string. There is not difference to the value. For instance `"aa"=='aa'`. No difference. I cannot really help you if I cannot reproduce this. If you can produce a fiddle that I can run, I can help.

Comment: you are 100% correct it is not the quotes, it works when I omit volume from the output...OMG was a pain to find this out. Is there a way to drop volume key value pair from your code ?

Comment: posted a full example in fiddle, have a look https://jsfiddle.net/t67qmcpb/

Comment: in the fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/t67qmcpb/ it prints to console correctly as you coded it; but for some reason when setting the candleSeries.setData(b) to candleSeries.setData(result) on the last time  it breaks ? any ideas why?

Comment: The reason seems to be that `result` is not sorted by date, and `b` is. So sort `result` like this: `result.sort((a,b) => a.time.localeCompare(b.time));`

Comment: all this pain because of the sort : (  THanks so much more helping. Much appreciated!!!!!!